# (libgdx) Why is my sprite being rendered so large?

Tags: java, libgdx, scale, tiled

I'm currently trying to learn the LibGDX game engine for java. I'm using a Tiled map, with each tiled being 32*32 pixels. I also have a character sprite with size 48*64. In my game, I'm defining one unit as one tile from the map. For some reason, my map gets rendered correctly, but the player sprite gets rendered abnormally large instead of in its expected size of roughly 2 square units.

I've tried searching for similar issues online, but cannot find anything just like my issue. I know it has something to do with the scaling I'm using, but I don't know of a good way to solve it.

One way is of course to simply scale down the player sprite when drawing it with the batch.draw() function, but I feel like that shouldn't be necessary.

@Override
    public void create () {

```
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -20), true); //Create Box2d world
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    player1 = new Player();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT); //Create the camera I'm using, with width = height = 20

    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/Maptest.tmx"); //Load a map created in Tiled
    this.mapObjects = map.getLayers().get(0).getObjects();
    ObjectMapper.createShapes(this.mapObjects, this.world); //Load shapes from map for collision management
    ObjectMapper.setSpawn(player1, mapObjects, world); //Set spawnpoint from object in the Tiled map

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1/PPT); //Create a tiled map renderer with unit scale 1/32


    camera.update();
}



@Override
public void render () {
    player1.update(); //Update player position

    camera.position.set(player1.getX(), player1.getY(), 0); //Set position to players position
    camera.update();



    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderer.setView(camera); //Set renderer's view to camera view
    renderer.render();
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(player1.getSprite(), player1.getX()-player1.getSprite().getWidth()/2, player1.getY()-player1.getSprite().getHeight()/2); //Draw player sprite
    batch.end();
    System.out.println(player1.getX() + " " + player1.getY());
    world.step(1/60f, 6, 2); //Iterate one step with Box2d world
    debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined); //Draw shapes

    long javaHeap = Gdx.app.getJavaHeap();
    long nativeHeap = Gdx.app.getNativeHeap();
}


@Override
public void resize (int width, int height) { 

    camera.viewportWidth = WORLD_WIDTH;                 // 20 units
    camera.viewportHeight = (float)WORLD_HEIGHT*height/width;
    camera.update();

}
```

I expect the sprite to be about the same size as the players hitbox (the circleshape) which has a radius of one unit. Instead, it becomes very large:

https://i.gyazo.com/6d814d10cd5f9bec322b601d538cb9ee.png

While the full sprite looks like this:

https://i.gyazo.com/03178769d4a3b4beaba1612c76d37386.png

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using the Sprite class altogether. In LibGDX it was created as a highly optimized thing, but it conflates an asset (TextureRegion) with a game model object (a position and size, etc.), and violates the composition over inheritance guideline. It also causes many questions here on StackOverflow because people don't realize that it inherits from TextureRegion but is not meant to be drawn by passing it to SpriteBatch (it's not meant to be treated like a TextureRegion). To draw it correctly, you are supposed to call `sprite.draw(batch)`, not `batch.draw(sprite, ...)`.

You already have a Player class. It should just reference a TextureRegion instead of a Sprite. You can give your Player class a size and position (the size you actually want it to be).